# docker-compose cannot create network conflicts with network, networks have overlapping IPv4

Tags: docker, nginx, networking

I have a number of dev sites I need to dockerise and run locally. I need to give them fixed IP's as they use callbacks from services which need to always hit the same IP.

On my first docker stack it works perfectly

```
php-fpm:
  image: php:fpm
  container_name: site1-php-fpm
  working_dir: /application
  networks:
    site1:
      ipv4_address: 172.18.0.5
.......
.......
.......

networks:
  site1:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
```

I can access the services via 172.18.0.1/2/3/4/5 as specified in the yaml file. The problem comes when trying to create the next site like so:

```
php-fpm:
  image: php:fpm
  container_name: site1-php-fpm
  working_dir: /application
  networks:
    site2:
      ipv4_address: 172.18.1.5
.......
.......
.......

networks:
  site2:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.18.1.0/16
```

My plan was to use 172.18.1.0, 172.18.2.0, 172.18.3.0..... and so on but I get this error:

```
cannot create network bc0ef736dbefd4622b5ca304e35fe8be3d071fc86ad45b41a161ea300c9ef929 (br-bc0ef736dbef): conflicts with network 2a52c21c5e042d56c47c032d78141c3413766ec6fb248e3a69ee9f794f38b70a (br-2a52c21c5e04): networks have overlapping IPv4
```

I thought 172.18.0.0 and 172.18.0.1 where different subnets? Or have I got this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub-network mask `/16` means that network prefix are the first 16 bits of the address, or in other words the first two numbers - `172.18.`. And in this case they are really overlapping. You have to change sub-network mask to `/24` or use different network prefix i.e. `172.18.`, `172.19.`, `172.20.` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar error:

> Creating network "elk_network1" with driver "bridge"
>   ERROR: cannot create network c64ac781783d8f020494700bedd0f4eed5751e1138f825ef91402134f395dd17 (br-c64ac781783d): conflicts with network 2d48f2e1eb3d16e16e958e52f4a2b48f5424e62ee961bccc4c44d8eff1aa18be (br-2d48f2e1eb3d): networks have overlapping IPv4

I have solved this problem like this following steps:

List all network

```
$ ip a
```

If you see the bridge like `br-2d48f2e1eb3d` and its status is down, delete it

```
$ brctl delbr br-2d48f2e1eb3d
```

Then restart docker

```
$ service docker restart
```

Run `docker-compose` again. Then `docker-compose` will run well.

But in your situation, you first need to change netmask to `/24`.

Comment: In my case this answer was the solution.